# Interpolation array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular2-template

If I try to access an element's property of an array like this:

```
{{myArray[0].myProperty}}
```

I get 'Runtime Error... Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined'

But if I use *ngFor I can access every property of each element in the array.
I'm missing something? How can I access a property of an specific element?

Comment: Are you getting array asynchronously?

Comment: Can you please include the `*ngFor` implementation

Comment: Yes asynchronously, but if I use the *ngFor, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using safe navigation operator. I suspect that first time your array is empty

```
{{ myArray[0]?.myProperty }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<YOUR_TAG *ngIf="myArray">{{myArray[0].myProperty}}</YOUR_TAG>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.